# Creating alias to function

Tags: c++, alias

I am willing to create an alias which looks like this:

```
using window = Window::instance().getWindow();
```

`Window::instance().getWindow()` returns pointer to the `sf::RenderWindow` type object, I want to shorten the inscription to make it more convenient to use.

Alias call would be smth like this:
`window->draw(object);`
Instead of:
`Window::instance().getWindow()->draw(object);`

Is it possible in C++?

Comment: Why not use `auto`?

Comment: Is the result of `Window::instance().getWindow()` persistent? Or does it change from call to call? There's no way to answer your question without knowing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure the returned pointer doesn't change between calls, you can save it temporarily:

```
auto window = Window::instance().getWindow();
```

Another **bad❌** approach is to use a macro:

```
#define window (Window::instance().getWindow())
```

But remember to parenthesize it in case operator precedence messes up.

Comment: Recommend not even listing the bad approach, but if you must, mark it with a skull and crossbones and put it dead last.

Comment: Why is the approach with use of #define so bad?

Comment: @Chris.Frog For example this code `something.window.blah` will be messed up.

Comment: Understood, so basically when using: auto window = Window::instance().getWindow(); before main(), window is just a sf::RenderWindow* type global variable?

Comment: @Chris.Frog: Yes.

Comment: @iBug: You are wrong, functions CAN be called before `main()`, if they are used to initialize global variables. See this [live demo](https://ideone.com/Mw0gYL). So, my reply applies to before `main()` as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Suggested by its name, I don't think it returns anything reasonable if called before `main()`. Though you're right that functions **can** be called then. I stand corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `auto`:
so instead of

```
Window::instance().getWindow()->draw(object);
```

you will have:

```
auto* window = Window::instance().getWindow();
window->draw(object);
```

Comment: auto did it's job, but I noticed that it also works without * after auto keyword. Why it works both ways and can it mess something up?

Comment: @Chris.Frog: `getWindow()` has a fixed return type (`sf::RenderWindow*`).  If you use `auto window`, `auto` will resolve to the exact same type (`sf::RenderWindow*`).  If you use `auto* window`, the compiler knows `getWindow()` returns a pointer so `auto` will resolve to the type being pointed at (`sf::RenderWindow`).  Either way, you end up with a `sf::RenderWindow*` pointer

Comment: I would say that the main reason to put an `*` is to confirm you have a pointer. Thus using `*` or `&` whenever it is appropriate might help ensure that you don't make unexpected copies even if you decide to refactor some code to use references instead of pointers and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

`using` is only for types and namespaces.  What you want is a simple pointer variable:

```
sf::RenderWindow *window = Window::instance().getWindow();
```

which can be shortened in C++11 and later using `auto`:

```
auto *window = Window::instance().getWindow();
```